# how to create combinatorial combination of two files

Tags: python-2.7, combinations

I did some research but i have difficulties finding an answer.
I am using python 2.7 and pandas so far but i am still learning.
I have two CSVs, let say it's the alphabet A-Z in one and digits in the second one, 0-100.
I want to merge the two files to have A0 to A100 up through Z.
For information the two files have DNA sequence so i believe they are strings.
I tried to create arrays with numpy and create a matrix but to no available..
here is a preview of the files:

```
    barcode
0   GGAAGAA
1   CCAAGAA
2   GAGAGAA
3   AGGAGAA
4   TCGAGAA
5   CTGAGAA
6   CACAGAA
7   TGCAGAA
8   ACCAGAA
9   GTCAGAA
10  CGTAGAA
11  GCTAGAA
12  GAAGGAA
13  AGAGGAA
14  TCAGGAA
659
     barcode
0   CGGAAGAA
1   GCGAAGAA
2   GGCAAGAA
3   GGAGAGAA
4   CCAGAGAA
5   GAGGAGAA
6   ACGGAGAA
7   CTGGAGAA
8   CACGAGAA
9   AGCGAGAA
10  TCCGAGAA
11  GTCGAGAA
12  CGTGAGAA
13  GCTGAGAA
14  CGACAGAA
1995
```

Comment: What's the significance of those `659` and `1995`? Are those input, or output files? What have the shown files to do with _alphabet A-Z_ and _digits … 0-100_?

Comment: Could you show what's the expected output of the combinations?

Comment: @Armali, The 359 and 1995 are the print(len(df)) of the two dataframes.

Comment: @Franco Piccolo, the expected output would be for the letter and digit analogy, A0 , A1, .. A100, B1, B2... ...Z100.

Comment: I am putting here the way i found to do it, there might be a sexier way:
'code'
    index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df8.barcode, df7.barcode], names = ["df8", "df7"])
df = pd.DataFrame(index = index).reset_index()
def concat_BC(x):#concatenate the 3 indexes into 1 BC
    return str(x["df8"]) + str(x["df7"])
df["BC"] = df.apply(concat_BC, axis=1)

Comment: I don't understand how the ADN's should be used. Could you provide exactly the input data and output expected?

Comment: @FrancoPiccolo 
Here is the input data
df7
   barcode
0   GGAAGAA
1   CCAAGAA
2   GAGAGAA
3   AGGAGAA
4   TCGAGAA
5   CTGAGAA
6   CACAGAA
7   TGCAGAA
8   ACCAGAA
9   GTCAGAA
10  CGTAGAA
11  GCTAGAA
12  GAAGGAA
13  AGAGGAA
14  TCAGGAA
659
df8
     barcode
0   CGGAAGAA
1   GCGAAGAA
2   GGCAAGAA
3   GGAGAGAA
4   CCAGAGAA
5   GAGGAGAA
6   ACGGAGAA
7   CTGGAGAA
8   CACGAGAA
9   AGCGAGAA
10  TCCGAGAA
11  GTCGAGAA
12  CGTGAGAA
13  GCTGAGAA
14  CGACAGAA
1995
I just wanted to make all the combinations between rows of df7 and df8

Answer (score 0):

I am putting here the way i found to do it, there might be a sexier way:

```
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df8.barcode, df7.barcode], names = ["df8", "df7"])
df = pd.DataFrame(index = index).reset_index()
def concat_BC(x):#concatenate the two sequences into one new column
    return str(x["df8"]) + str(x["df7"])
df["BC"] = df.apply(concat_BC, axis=1)
```

– Stephane Chiron